# how to check this special strings

Tags: php, regex

I have a special strings to check with a PHP script. This is the format :

```
XX - XX:XX:XX - Somethings
```

such as :

1. each XX must be `??` or a pair of digit;
2. first XX can take every kind of digit;
3. second XX must be from 00 and 10;
4. third and fourth XX must be from 00 to 59;
5. somethings can be everything, it doesnt matter;

These are some example :

```
00 - ??:??:?? - Blablabla // OK
99 - ??:99:?? - Blablabla // NO (99 is too high)
99 - 12:50:40 - Blablabla // NO (12 is too high)
?? - AA:50:40 - Blablabla // NO (AA is not a pair of digit)
99 - 2:50:40 - Blablabla // NO (2 is not a pair of digit; I need 02)
99 -08:49:40 - Blablabla // NO (-08 need a space)
```

How can I do it? I think the best way is Regex, but I really don't know how to do it :) Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried reading e.g. the manual? (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)  What *specific* problems are you facing?

Comment: For example I don't know how to say "is number of 2 digit from 0 to 10" :)

Comment: What’s so “special” about the bunch of characters?

Comment: 00 to 10 seems a strange range for the 2nd number, I'd have expected 00 to 23 ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$subj = '00 - 04:38:27 - Hi';
preg_match('/^(\?\?|\d\d) - (\?\?|10|0\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d):(\?\?|[0-5]\d) - (.*)/', $subj, $matches);
```

Then you can access the fields in matches:

```
$matches[1] = 00
$matches[2] = 04
$matches[3] = 38
$matches[4] = 27
$matches[5] = Hi
```

Comment: Seems to work! You really rock!!! It save me many lines of code :) And I've understand why it works! Hehe. Just one things : what mean '/ at the start of the regex? and / at the end?

Comment: It is how regexes are written in perl (enclosed by slashes). And since PHP is loosely based on perl, it has inherited that syntax. You can f.ex. write flags to the regex engine after the terminating slash, like '/.../i' (wich makes it case-insenitive).

Comment: I added an ^ at the beginning, by courtesy of Wh1T3h4Ck5; otherwise the pattern will match lines that might not match your format. Make sure to get that change.

Comment: I've just posted (than removed) comment about ^. You were quicker +1.

Comment: Uhm...added! But still don't understand these symbols at the start/end. Now the ^ too :)

Comment: Okay, the / are required, and _not_ part of the regex, the ^ means beginning of string; without them the pattern would match 'asdhgasdjghajgsghd00 - ??:??:?? - Blablabla'. Any other parts that are unclear?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job (tested at http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)
`/([0-9\?]{2} - (0[0-9]|10|\?\?):([0-5][0-9]|\?\?):([0-5][0-9]|\?\?) - .*)/`